# Laravel - diferencia entre dos datetimes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, php7, laravel-6

tengo una tabla "Registers" con un campo "datetime" y en ella tengo un campo que es "diff" de tipo varchar.

Lo que hago en la lógica del proyecto cuando inserto un registro en dicha tabla si existe otro registro que cumple los requisitos hago una resta entre las dos fechas y lo guardo en el campo "diff"

La resta la hago de esta forma

```
 <?php
 $aux1 = $register->date;
 $aux2 = $ultimo_registro->date;

 $aux3 = $aux1->diff($aux2)->format('%H:%I:%S');
```

Esto me devuelve un resultado del tipo "04:31:31" y como "diff" es un campo varchar lo puedo guardar perfectamente.

El "problema" lo tengo cuando tengo "N" registros de este tipo como puedo sumar estos campos...porque son varchar.
Igual esta mal planteado y deberia guardar la diferencia entre las 2 fechas en formato "unix timestamp"

Comment: ¿Deseas sumar las diferencias que tienes almacenadas en varios registros?

Comment: Si, imaginate que tengo 10 registros, quiero saber la diferencia del 1º con el 2º, luego del 2º con el 3º...asi sucesivamente, actualmente lo hago de la forma anterior y guardo en un campo varchar el resultado en formato '%H:%I:%S', pero si luego deseo sumar esos campos no puedo.